# group by using anonymous type in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let say I have an Employee class, and GetAllEmployees() return a list of employee instance. I want to group employees by Department and Gender, so the answer I have is

```
var employeeGroup = Employee.GetAllEmployees()
                            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Department, x.Gender }) // I don't understand this anonymous type
                            .OrderBy(g => g.Key.Department)
                            .ThenBy(g => g.Key.Gender)
                            .Select(g => new {   //I can understand this anonymous type
                               Dept = g.Key.Department,
                               Gender = g.Key.Gender,
                               Employees = g.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                             });
```

I have two questions:

1. Why an anonymous type allows a multiple keys group by?
2. I don't understand the first anonymous type, because from my understanding, an anonymous type's format should be like this

   new { field1 = x.Department, field2 = x.Gender }

How come the first anonymous type can have without fields? I mean, it's correct syntax to write something like this:

```
var anonymous = new {field1 = 1,field2 =2}
```

But there will be compile error if I write it like this:

```
var anonymous = new {1, 2} //compile error !!!
```

Comment: `field1` and `field2` are the fields. When you `select` you are doing a projection into an anonymous type, when you `groupBy` you are getting something different: `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`

Comment: If you omit the `field = ` part, the fieldname is taken from the variable/property. See [`anonymous types`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/765/anonymous-types/2612/creating-an-anonymous-type#t=201701021356107409379)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ GroupBy Anonymous Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793416/linq-groupby-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Anonymous types can be used here to group by multiple fields, because `GroupBy` uses the default equality comparer.
The default equality comparer for anonymous types uses the default equality comparer for each property of the anonymous type.

So for the first anonymous type, two instances are equal if both `Department`s and both `Gender`s are equal (according to their default equality comparers).

You can imagine the anonymous type being something like that:

```
public class AnonymousType1
{
    public int Department { get; set; } // I don't know your department type
    public int Gender { get; set; } // neither your gender type

    public int GetHashCode() { return Department.GetHashCode() ^ Gender.GetHashCode(); }
    public bool Equals(AnonymousType1 other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
        return Department == other.Department && Gender == other.Gender;
    }
}
```

---

The second question is easy, too: The compiler uses the property names (`Department` from `x.Department` and `Gender` from `x.Gender`) as names for the properties of the anonymous type.

So

```
var anon = new { employee.Department, employee.Gender }
```

creates a type with a property called `Department` and a property called `Gender`.
Of course this can only work with existing properties/names, not with constant values like

```
var anon = new {1,2}; // fails to compile, no names provided.
```

Comment: GroupBy() requires an immutable class. An anonymous one is immutable.