# LINQ GroupBy for multiple Column

Tags: c#, linq

I am stuck in logic to group by. I have a model that has all information but I have to group information according to `CustomerBuildingMapping`

```
public class TicketsDataModel
{
    public string BuildingID { get; set; }
    public string Ticket { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
}
```

Current Data

```
BuildingID | Ticket | Amount |CustomerID | BuildingName 
10         | 001    | 50     | 1         | JP Building
11         | 002    | 45     | 1         | Tiskon
52         | 452    | 35     | 2         | Lalit
65         | 568    | 78     | 2         | Tuilp
41         | 121    | 12     | 1         | BK Trp
```

-

```
public class CustomerBuildingMapping
{
    public long LeadID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public List<BuildingInfo> BuildingInfo{ get; set; }
}
public class BuildingInfo
{
    public string BuildingID { get; set; }
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
    public long Amount { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
}
```

Expected Data after group by

```
LeadID 1001
CustomerID 1
BuildingInfo
               BuildingID | Ticket | Amount  | BuildingName 
               10         | 001    | 50      | JP Building
               11         | 002    | 45      | Tiskon
               41         | 121    | 12      | BK Trp
LeadID 1002
CustomerID 2
BuildingInfo
               BuildingID | Ticket | Amount  | BuildingName 
               52         | 452    | 35      | Lalit
               65         | 568    | 78      | Tulip
```

I have written this code but not able to group by for multiple columns.

```
List<CustomerBuildingMapping> objCustomerBuildingMappingResult = objTicketsForTheDayInfo.TicketsForTheDay.GroupBy(l => l.CustomerID).Select(grp => new CustomerBuildingMapping
            {
                CustomerID = grp.Key,
                //BuildingInfo = grp.Select(l => l.BuildingID).ToList(),
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Where does the lead id come from? is it generated? and how (what criteria)?

Comment: @Nkosi every customerID have a leadId,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to group by multiple columns. Based on sample data you are only grouping by one field, `CustomerID`.

```
var objCustomerBuildingMappingResult = objTicketsForTheDayInfo.TicketsForTheDay
.GroupBy(l => l.CustomerID)
.Select(grp => new CustomerBuildingMapping
        {
            CustomerID = grp.Key,
            LeadId = long.Parse(grp.Key) + 1000,
            BuildingInfo = grp.Select(l => new BuildingInfo {
                BuildingID = l.BuildingID,
                TicketNumber = l.Ticket,
                Amount = l.Amount,
                BuildingName = l.BuildingName
            }).ToList(),
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nkosi has pointed out, in OP's example, because `LeadId` is an automatically generated surrogate key, there's no need to `GroupBy` on anything other than a single key field (`CustomerID`), and make a function to generate the surrogate `LeadId`.

However, in the more general case, if a composite key needs to be constructed for a `GroupBy`, then both types of `Tuples` *(`System.Tuple` on older versions of C#, and `System.ValueTuple` in C#7 and later)* make for good transient grouping keys when used with `.GroupBy` and `.ToDictionary`. This is because Tuples internally build the tuple instance's HashCode [by combining the underlying Hashcodes of the contained types](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,52).

**For the older System.Tuple, you need to deal with the ugly `Itemx` properties:**

```
var objCustomerBuildingMappingResult = objTicketsForTheDayInfo
        .TicketsForTheDay
        .GroupBy(l => Tuple.Create(l.CustomerID, l.BuildingID))
        .Select(grp => new CustomerBuildingMapping
        {
            CustomerID = grp.Key.Item1,
            BuildingId = grp.Key.Item2,
            // ...
        })
        .ToList();
```

**But this is more readable (and performant) with System.ValueTuple:**

```
var objCustomerBuildingMappingResult = objTicketsForTheDayInfo
        .TicketsForTheDay
        .GroupBy(l => (CustomerId: l.CustomerID, BuildingId: l.BuildingID))
        .Select(grp => new CustomerBuildingMapping
        {
            CustomerID = grp.Key.CustomerId,
            BuildingId = grp.Key.BuildingID,
            // ...
```

Comment: Might want to compare tuples vs [anon types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428241/314291) as composite grouping keys