# How to create a moq unit test when grouping by class

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, group-by, moq

This is my code:

```
var data = context.GetAll<UserRole>()
   .GroupBy(x => new RoleGroup { RoleId = x.RoleId, AccessEnum = x.AccessEnum })
   .Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

This is the data mock:

```
var userRoles = new List<UserRole>
{
    new UserRole { Id = 1, RoleId = 1, AccessEnum = AccessEnum.Full },
    new UserRole { Id = 2, RoleId = 1, AccessEnum = AccessEnum.Full },
    new UserRole { Id = 3, RoleId = 2, AccessEnum = AccessEnum.ReadOnly },
    new UserRole { Id = 4, RoleId = 2, AccessEnum = AccessEnum.Full },
    new UserRole { Id = 5, RoleId = 2, AccessEnum = AccessEnum.ReadOnly }
};
mockContext.Setup(x => x.GetAll<UserRole>()).Returns(userRoles.AsQuerable());
```

The GroupBy works fine when using the system. However when I run a unit test it returns each record individually. If I change the `GroupBy` to an anonymous object, it does work:

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.RoleId, x.AccessEnum })
```

But I need to pass the list into another method. So I need to define the key as a `RoleGroup`.

Is there a way to get this working by keeping the class in the `GroupBy`?

Comment: what is the return value of `GetAll` ?

Comment: It returns an IQuerable of UserRole

Comment: how do you initialize mockContext before setup?

Comment: Its just a standard Mock.

protected Mock<IDatabaseContext> MockContext { get; set; }

Comment: Then its just newed up as normal.  

MockContext = new Mock<IDatabaseContext>();

Comment: the problem cause by the way you use GroupBy not relate to the Mock see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428128/group-by-using-anonymous-type-in-linq) for the new RoleGroup in GroupBy the comparator cannot map instance of 2 object with the same value. To understand group by [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)