# LINQ GroupBY Query returns different answers

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0

I have a question about the LINQ GroupBy function. I noticed that although the same grouping function is used, the result is different depending on the model.

I read a lot of datasets from a database to a variable which is called data. This list contains ~12.000 elements and i would like to group it by a card-id, the date and first and last-name of the user. The problem is, that when i am using a "Model" like the GroupListModel below, the result is not like expected.

The GroupListModel looks like the following:

```
public class GroupListModel
{
        public string CardId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (!(obj is GroupListModel))
            return false;

        GroupListModel model = (GroupListModel)obj;

        return (this.CardId.Equals(model.CardId) 
            && this.FirstName.Equals(model.FirstName)
            && this.LastName.Equals(model.LastName)
            && DateTime.Compare(this.Date, model.Date)==0);
    }
}
```

My first GroupBy Statement for example is:

```
data.GroupBy(x => new GroupListModel
{
    CardId = x.CardId,
    Date = x.Date.Value,
    FirstName = esdUsersForTheDepartments
        .Where(y=>y.CardId.Equals(x.CardId))
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .FirstName,
    LastName = esdUsersForTheDepartments
        .Where(y => y.CardId.Equals(x.CardId))
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .LastName
}).ToList();
```

My second GroupBy Statement is without a Model Creation approach:

```
data.GroupBy(x => new
{
    CardId = x.CardId,
    Date = x.Date.Value,
    FirstName = esdUsersForTheDepartments
        .Where(y => y.CardId.Equals(x.CardId))
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .FirstName,
    LastName = esdUsersForTheDepartments
        .Where(y => y.CardId.Equals(x.CardId))
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .LastName
}).ToList();
```

What i noticed is, that the Group-Function in Statement 1 is returning in my opinion a wrong result. The second one is working as expected.

Could someone explain me this behaviour?

Comment: Can we have a look at `GroupListModel` definition?

Comment: May I ask why you'd want to do that? Because overriding `GroupListModel.Equals()` introduces more code, that can have bugs and subtle performance traps (don't forget to override `GetHashCode()` too). What's the benefit? If you only wan't to return `IGrouping<TKey, TData>` from a method then you could use value tuples as well.

Answer (score 3):

To make `GroupListModel` override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for you, you can change it into a `record`.

```
public record GroupListModel
{
     public string CardId { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This way it will behave similar to an anonymous type.

Comment: I have overrided the Equals methode like in the model shown. What should i do by GetHashCode?

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler Just use a record and you won't have to override either of them.

Comment: If you change from class to record you dont need to override them. It will be handled for you.

Comment: actually this answer would be a nice addition to the duplicate post. Since it is 6 years old and from before the times of records.

Answer (score 2):

the equality comparison in anonymous objects is done by the comparison of the individual properties. This is in detail explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428241/5174469) Which is the second example that you have posted.

The comparison of already defined classes like `GroupListModel` is done via the equals method, which in this case is the default method.

To yield the same result you would have to override the `Equals` method and implement the comparison based on the properties in your group clause

Comment: And what should i do to get it working? Should i override the Equals Method?

Comment: I wasn't fast enough with typing. But yes that would be the case, but on the pragmatic side you would duplicate the comparison code and make it rigid by doing so

Comment: i have added the following code like shown in my question, but it's anyways not working.

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler whenever you override `Equals` you must also override `GetHashCode` In code that does comparisons often it is optimized to compare hashcodes first, and only if the hashcodes match will it check if `Equals` also returns true.

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler actually I just found a duplicate. So I will close this now